# Hiding and Unhiding App icon in the launcher

Tags: android

I am currently  implementing a feature to hide and unhide app icon in the launcher based on some certain condition.

I have succeeded in hiding the icon. However, I am finding it difficult to bring the app icon back except that I re-install the application.

Is there a way to make it possible to hide and unhide without having to re-install the application.

#### To hide

```kotlin
       findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt).setOnClickListener {
            val p: PackageManager = packageManager
            val componentName = ComponentName(
                this,
                MainActivity::class.java
            ) // activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            p.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                componentName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
            )
        }
```

#### To show

```kotlin
       findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt).setOnClickListener {
            val p: PackageManager = packageManager
            val componentName = ComponentName(
                this,
                MainActivity::class.java
            ) // activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            p.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                componentName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
            )
        }
```

Comment: "However, I am finding it difficult to bring the app icon back except that I re-install the application" -- what did you try? For example, did you try rebooting the device? The launcher might not be observing state changes correctly and might only detect the change when it restarts.

Comment: Yeah I just rebooted the device but the changes wont take effect. I also tried to add launcher category programmatically and launch the app after reboot but the app icon wont return.

Comment: @CommonsWare any help yet. Sorry for any inconvenience pls